# How to add mutliple dendencies in Makefile

Tags: linux-kernel, makefile, centos

I have simple module program which will call to other function which are in other files. eg:

```
   Arith.c <=== main module which calls sum(), diff(), mul() ...
    |
    |----sum.c 
    |----Sub.c
    |----mul.c
    |----div.c
            |----remainder.c
            |----quotient.c
```

I wrote the program for it. For make file I didn't understand how to write. I studied [section 3.3 here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt) and edited `Makefile`.

So now my make file is (I tested only for sum)

```
obj-m := arith.o
arith-y += sum.o

KDIR=/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

module: 
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean
```

When I run `make` it compiled and generated `arith.ko`. When I inserted it not showing anything in `dmesg`. When I inserted other modules `dmesg` working properly.

arith.c:

```
extern void sum(void);

int init_module(void)
{
        pr_info("module inserted..\n");
        sum();

        return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
        pr_info("module removed..\n");

}
```

sum.c:

```
void sum(void)
{
        pr_info("sum of 1 and 2: %d\n", 1+2);
}
```

Additional Info:

If I comment `arith-y += sum.o` in `Makefile` and not calling `sum` function in `arith.c`, `dmesg` working correctly.

**Questions**:

1.Is that make file correct?

2.If it is correct, why `arith` module not showing anything in `dmesg` even other modules working fine?

3.If it is not correct, how to write `Makefile` and why?

Answer (score 0):

You never refer to `obj-m` or `arith-y` after declaring them; so they are either:

- some sort of **magic** that your `make` knows about (which I doubt),
- normal variables which you need to **reference** somewhere else, or
- **dead code**.

You might have more luck looking through the kernel tree for a simple makefile which you can read and understand in detail.

Comment: They appear to be variables used by the makefile in `$(KDIR)`.